# Does Bash or AWK have IN operator like R programming Language?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, r

In R, We have IN operator to check whether or not the element is present in the specific column.

For example: If we have fruits and market dataframe with fruit_name and products as the column name respectively. And, say, we have to check what fruits are present in the market.

In R,

```
available_fruit <- fruits$fruit_name %in% market$products
```

Is there any operator in bash or AWK which does similar action like %in% in R?

Comment: What's a "dataframe"?

Comment: A dataframe is a datatype in R.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html

Comment: please check  http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html

Answer (score 4):

`awk` has an `in` operator.  It may be used to access the indexes in an array (arrays are associative arrays/hashes in `awk`).

If the names of the fruits are keys in the array `market` then you may use

```
if (fruit_name in market) { ... }
```

to check whether the string in `fruit_name` is a key in `market`.

For example

```
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }

NR == FNR { market[$1] = $2; next }

!($1 in market) { printf("No %s in the market\n", $1 ); next }

{ sum += market[$1] }

END { printf("Total sum is %.2f\n", sum ) }
```

Running this on two files:

```
$ awk -f script.awk market_prices mylist
```

where `market_prices` is a two-column tab delimited file with items and prices, and `mylist` is a list of items. The script would read the items and their prices from the first file and populate `market` with these, and then calculate the total cost of the items in the second file, if they existed in the market, reporting the items that can't be found.

The `in` operator may also be used to loop over the indexes of an array:

```
for (i in array) {
    print i, array[i]
}
```

The ordering of the indexes may not be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Awk and Bash have associative arrays, which do provide a way to find if a certain *key/index* is in the array.

in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ a["foo"]=1; if ("foo" in a) print "yea"; }'
```

in Bash:

```
bash -c 'declare -A a=([foo]=1); if [[ ${a[foo]+x} = x ]]; then echo "yea"; fi'
```

(`${a[foo]+x}` evaluates to `x` if `a[foo]` is set, to the empty string otherwise)

---

But you can't easily find if a particular value exists in the *values* of array elements. Here, `a[1]` is `foo`, but the test doesn't find it (it would find the indices `1`, `2` and `3`):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ split("foo bar doo", a); if ("foo" in a) print "foo exists?"; }'
```

you'll have to walk the array manually:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ split("foo bar doo", a); for (i in a) if (a[i] == "foo") print "foo exists"; }'
```

or in Bash:

```
bash -c 'a=(foo bar doo); for v in "${a[@]}"; do 
         if [[ $v = "foo" ]]; then echo "foo exists"; fi; done;'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Awk, you can check if an index is in an array with the `in` operator:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {arr["foo"]=1; arr["bar"]=2; print "foo" in arr}'
1
```

What this is doing is defining an array `arr[]` with two values: `arr[foo]=1; arr[bar]=2`.

Then, `"foo" in arr` checks if the index `foo` is in the set of indeces defined in such array. Since this is true, the `print` returns 1.

This is described in [GNU Awk User's Guide → 8.1.2 Referring to an Array Element](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reference-to-Elements):

> To determine whether an element exists in an array at a certain index, use the following expression:
>
> ```
> indx in array
> ```